# How do I make this GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've been tasked to make a GUI in Java by using "swing" which is an exact replica of the image below. It doesn't have to have any functionality, it's just for looks. However, there's this one part of this image I can't find or make, which is the top right corner "gender" box. How do I make that transparent-looking box that has an outline? Please help me out, and thank you!

[image: All I want to know is how to make that transparent box, that has the "Gender" heading.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called a `TitledBorder`.

**Example:**

```
public class SwingTester {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      createWindow();
   }

   private static void createWindow() {    
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Tester");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      createUI(frame);
      frame.setSize(560, 200);      
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   private static void createUI(JFrame frame){
      //Create a border
      Border blackline = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Title");
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      LayoutManager layout = new FlowLayout();  
      panel.setLayout(layout);       

      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
      String spaces = "                   ";

      panel1.add(new JLabel(spaces + "Title border to JPanel" + spaces));  
      panel1.setBorder(blackline);

      panel.add(panel1);
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);    
   }
}
```

[image]

For your case, update this line with your own title:

```
Border blackline = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Title");  //change to gender
```

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swingexamples/add_title_to_border_panel.htm

Comment: @Anonymous If this solves your question, you can click on the tick beside my solution :)

Comment: Oh im now getting this error that states, "Border cannot be resolved to type". Do I have to import AWT or something?

Comment: @Anonymous You can visit the link in my solution. It shows you the list of Java libraries to be imported. For your border, you need to `import javax.swing.border.Border;` .

Comment: Doesnt "import java.swing.*;" import all of already?

Comment: @Anonymous I am afraid not. If I remember correctly `.*` only import all things one level down i.e `swing.xxx` but it doesn't import `swing.xxx.yyy`.

Comment: I edited the opening line to remove the reference to `JPanel`. Although panels have the lion's share of borders, a border can be added to any `JComponent`. One occasional example is a `JLabel`. **If** a component already has a border (e.g. `JButton` or `JScrollPane`) it ***then*** makes sense to add the component to a panel and set the border of the panel. But not always.